# Grouping by property in referenced entity

Tags: jekyll

I have a Jekyll project that contains products (in a collection). Each product has a company, which is a reference to an entity in the `companies` collection. Each company then has its own properties (for the sake of the example, let's say it has a `country` property).

How can I list products and group them by the company's country? Can I "project" the company's properties on the collection I'm actually working with (in this case, the products collection)? Or am I limited to properties of the collection being enumerated?

Comment: I think you're looking for a `where` or possibly a `where_exp` filter: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/. I'm a very visual person and can't understand what you're trying to achieve without more help. Do you have a link to the repo? Can you give an example of expected output?

Comment: @BradWest Yes, I have a repo, but I went for a concise example for the sake of the minimal case. Mind it, though, AFAIK (and AFAITried) `where` only works with properties of the elements of the collection I'm working on - so in this case the products. I can easily group theme by company, but what if I wanted to "supergroup" the products by their company's country?